# After cleaning RAM app crashes when resuming android app (NullPointerException)

Tags: android, eclipse, memory, crash

I have a problem with my app. I searched for a solution on stackoverflow, but i didn't find one.

I'm still a beginner in developing android apps. I created my first app on my own in the last week.

The problem: When I start the app everything works fine. Also when I start my app, go to menu and resume immediately, but when i switch to menu, clean my memory and then restart my app, it seems, that the app was still running, because it crashes now. I have a similar effect when I start the app, switch to some other apps and then return to my app. In this case, the app also crashes. 
So, why the app is still running, altough I cleaned my memory? Should I override onFinish()- or onPause()-method with some basic code I don't know?
And why does the app crash, when i don't use it for a while?

LogCat:

```
12-18 23:19:06.850: E/AndroidRuntime(25262): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 23:19:06.850: E/AndroidRuntime(25262): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-18 23:19:06.850: E/AndroidRuntime(25262):    at de.dzapps.isoapp.IsoToleranzen.update(IsoToleranzen.java:1293)
12-18 23:19:06.850: E/AndroidRuntime(25262):    at de.dzapps.isoapp.IsoToleranzen$4.onItemClick(IsoToleranzen.java:441)
12-18 23:19:06.850: E/AndroidRuntime(25262):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
12-18 23:19:06.850: E/AndroidRuntime(25262):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1283)
12-18 23:19:06.850: E/AndroidRuntime(25262):    at de.dzapps.isoapp.IsoToleranzen$1.onGlobalLayout(IsoToleranzen.java:174)
12-18 23:19:06.850: E/AndroidRuntime(25262):    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnGlobalLayout(ViewTreeObserver.java:682)
12-18 23:19:06.850: E/AndroidRuntime(25262):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1875)
12-18 23:19:06.850: E/AndroidRuntime(25262):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1131)
12-18 23:19:06.850: E/AndroidRuntime(25262):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4611)
12-18 23:19:06.850: E/AndroidRuntime(25262):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
12-18 23:19:06.850: E/AndroidRuntime(25262):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
12-18 23:19:06.850: E/AndroidRuntime(25262):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
12-18 23:19:06.850: E/AndroidRuntime(25262):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
12-18 23:19:06.850: E/AndroidRuntime(25262):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
12-18 23:19:06.850: E/AndroidRuntime(25262):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-18 23:19:06.850: E/AndroidRuntime(25262):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-18 23:19:06.850: E/AndroidRuntime(25262):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
12-18 23:19:06.850: E/AndroidRuntime(25262):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 23:19:06.850: E/AndroidRuntime(25262):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-18 23:19:06.850: E/AndroidRuntime(25262):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
12-18 23:19:06.850: E/AndroidRuntime(25262):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
12-18 23:19:06.850: E/AndroidRuntime(25262):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Since I get a NullPointerException, it seems, that the system deletes the variables...
But when I doubleclick the third line, eclipse marks this line:

```
int am_offset = list.getChildAt(0).getTop();
```

I can't explain this behaviour, because I set a breakpoint at this line and the system never call this expression when I resume the app. `list` is a ListView.
How can I prevent, that the system deletes the variables, when then app is not used for a while?

Can somebody help me?

Many thanks!

Comment: Where and how are you initializing the `list`? What are you expecting `getChildAt(0)` to return? Could that be null?

Comment: getChildAt should throw an exception. AdapterViews can't have child views in the traditional sense. Looks like there are two problems here. One with Activity Lifecycle and the other with how to use an adapterview.

Comment: I initialize `list` in onCreate(). With `getChildAt(0).getTop()` I want to get the first visible item and its px that are not visible. That works fine when I start the app for the first time. And this also works fine, when I go to menu and resume immediatelly. But it doesn't work, when I clean the memory before resuming...

Comment: I think the problem is, that in onResume() the system doesn't know the px, which are not visible, maybe it doesn't even know the first item, but that should be okay, because this expression is just called by an onClickEvent. I set a breakpoint at this position and debugging mode confirms, that `int am_offset = list.getChildAt(0).getTop();` is never called, but nevertheless the app crashes at this point.

Comment: Ok I have a soulution. But there is still one point I don't understand. Can you please read my answer below and try to give a statement? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I have a solution. I replaced `int am_offset = list.getChildAt(0).getTop();` with:

```
View am_top = list.getChildAt(0);
am_offset = (am_top == null) ? 0 : am_top.getTop();
```

Now I don't get an exception anymore.

But can somebody explain to me, why the system throws an exception, altough `int am_offset = list.getChildAt(0).getTop();` is never called while resuming?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read, the system deleting variables should be more or less left alone as the system does what it must to keep device performance. It may help to avoid these NullPointerExceptions and restore state by writing safety checks in the onResume of the activity to recreate any lost variables. Also, if they hold data that must persist for long periods of time, [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) may be of some use for small values and an [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) for when there's a lot to save.